# Python: Concatenate all combinations of numpy array rows

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

In python need to combine two 2-dimensional numpy arrays, so that the resulting rows are combinations of the rows from the input arrays concatenated together. I need the fastest solution so it can be used in arrays that are very big.

For example:

I got:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array2 = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
```

I want the code to return:

```
[[1,2,5,6]
 [1,2,7,8]
 [3,4,5,6]
 [3,4,7,8]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution using numpy's [`repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), [`tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)

### The snippet

```
result = np.hstack([
    np.repeat(array1, array2.shape[0], axis=0),
    np.tile(array2, (array1.shape[0], 1))
])
```

### Step by step explanation

We start with the two arrays, `array1` and `array2`:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array2 = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
```

First, we duplicate the content of `array1` using `repeat`:

```
a = np.repeat(array1, array2.shape[0], axis=0)
```

The content of `a` is:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

Then we repeat the second array, `array2`, using `tile`. In particular, `(array1.shape[0],1)` replicates `array2` in the first direction `array1.shape[0]` times and just `1` time in the other direction.

```
b = np.tile(array2, (array1.shape[0],1))
```

The result is:

```
array([[5, 6],
       [7, 8],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

Now we can just proceed to stack the two results, using `hstack`:

```
result = np.hstack([a,b])
```

Achieving the desired output:

```
array([[1, 2, 5, 6],
       [1, 2, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [3, 4, 7, 8]])
```

Answer (score 1):

For this small example, `itertools.product` is actually faster.  I don't know how it scales

```
alist = list(itertools.product(array1.tolist(),array2.tolist()))
np.array(alist).reshape(-1,4)
```